# testing.exe has triggered a breakpoint

Tags: c++, c, pointers, computer-science

Whenever I keep trying to run this, I keep getting this exception thrown message. I was originally getting a lot of errors in a different function, however, now it keeps taking me back to this one.
The error it is showing is that it is at the initiation of the while loop, at least that is where the arrow is pointing.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>

void input(char* file_name, char* str) {
    FILE* fp;
    fp = fopen(file_name, "r"); 

    char ch;
    while ((ch = fgetc(fp)) != EOF) {
        *str++ = ch++;                 
    }
    *str = '\0';                   
}

int main() {
    char file_name[25] = "p3-in1.txt";

    int code[] = { 6, 2, -1, 3, 2, 4, -3, 3, 1, -5, 4 };
    int length = 11;

    char message[5000];
    input(file_name, message);
    encrypt(code, length, message, 0);
    output(message);
    encrypt(code, length, message, 1);
    output(message);

    return 0;
}
```

I am unsure about what to do about this as I have never had errors in similar code such as this in the past. Any help would be very appreciated!

If it would help, here is some other things this error is saying:

"Unhandled exception at 0x0FA8FC66 (ucrtbased.dll) in testing.exe: An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal."

My apologies everyone, I added the main so you could see it.

Comment: What size buffer does the caller pass for `str` parameter? Is it large enough to hold all the contents of the file? Does the file actually exist - does `fopen` succeed?

Comment: Use `std::string& str` instead of `char* str` and you will get success.

Comment: `*str++ = ch++; ` I'm not sure I understand why you are doing `ch++`? Why are you incrementing the character to the next one? Also, how are you running this with no `main`? Are you calling this as a linked library from another executable?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik I added in my main so that everyone could see. I apologize for that. I am fairly new to C, so I am unsure about how to answer some of these questions.

Comment: @S.M. Our professor wants us to use strictly pointers, so he said we had to use *char str as the parameter

Comment: @RonBeyer I was incrementing *str++ = ch++ each time so that it would add each ch into the str, incrementing the pointer each time to move from index to index

Comment: @axis100 But `ch` isn't a pointer... I get the `str++` part, but why increment ch?

Comment: My guess would be, `fopen` fails and returns a null pointer, and then `fgets` crashes. Either the file named `p3-in1.txt` doesn't exist, or the current working directory is not what you think it is.

Comment: Please remove one of the "C" or "C++" tags. They are different languages. -- Please [edit] your question and provide a real [mre]. The output part is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

I think FOpen is failing and it is returning a null because the file path given to fopen is not correct or file does not exist. Can you provide the absolute(full) file path of the file "p3-in1.txt" and try running the code.

i.e replace this code :-
char file_name[25] = "p3-in1.txt";
with this code:-
char file_name[25] = "C:\FULL_PATH\p3-in1.txt";

Note:- FULL_PATH = actual path of the file in you operating system (here i have assumed your running on windows)